# How do I extract the last trading day from a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a csv file which contains 30 years of stocks data. A portion of it looks like this:

[image: Stocks]

How can I extract the last trading date of a specific month of a specific stock, say the last trading month of June 2018 of stock s_0003?

This is my code, but it doesn't seem to be working for me because my output was 6/9/18. Is there something wrong with my code? Or is there another method I could use to extract the last trading date?

```
    df = pd.read_csv(stocks)

    new = df[['date', 's_0003']]
    jun = new[pd.to_datetime(new['date']).dt.month == 6]
    jun = jun[pd.to_datetime(jun['date']).dt.year == 2018]
    lastday = (max(jun['date']))

    stock0003 = df.loc[df["date"].isin([lastday]), "s_0003"]
```

Comment: Please replace your image by the dataframe as plain text.

Comment: did you check `.tail(1)` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by replacing the last 2 lines with these:

```
lastday = (max(pd.to_datetime(jun['date']).dt.day))

stock0003 = jun.loc[pd.to_datetime(jun['date']).dt.day == lastday, "s_0003"].iloc[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can just use tail/head depending on the sort order.

```
df = pd.read_csv(stocks)

df = df.sort_values('date')

print(df.tail(1))
```

This way we can be sure that the dataframe is sorted is ascending order before we take the last element.

Ref:

- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html
- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `Period` to extract the `year-month` from `date`, filter by the query string ('2018-06') and keep the last index.

```
QS = '2018-06'

df = pd.read_csv(stocks, parse_dates=['date']).sort_values('date')

stock0003 = df.loc[df['date'].dt.to_period('M').eq(QS).tail(1).index, 's_0003']
```

*`sort_values` is not mandatory if your dates are already sorted in your csv file.*

**A better idea is to set `date` column as index of your dataframe using `pd.read_csv(..., index_col = 'date')`**: